# Image from RSS Feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch, rss

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the image URL from my RSS feed. I have gotten other elements like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"]) {
    }
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"title"])
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [self setTitle:currentString];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqual:@"link"])
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [self setLink:currentString];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqual:@"description"])
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [self setInfoString:currentString];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqual:@"pubDate"])
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [self setDate:currentString];
    }
```

I need to get the image URL from the description element.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/bevins-002-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Jimmy Bevins and Scott County FB President Jimmy Richardson at the current site." style="display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; clear:both;" />Toyota and urban sprawl have changed Scott County to where agriculture no longer is the dominant force. But farmers there still have clout, and the farm community is united and optimistic about agriculture’s future. Just ask Bill or Jimmy Bevins. They can tell you about the tremendous growth of the 68-year-old Bevins Motors farm equipment [&#8230;]
]]>
</description>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Note: NSString *input would be your <description> element as a string        

    NSString *input = @"<description><![CDATA[<img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/bevins-002-150x150.jpg\" class=\"attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image\" alt=\"Jimmy Bevins and Scott County FB President Jimmy Richardson at the current site.\" style=\"display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; clear:both;\" />Toyota and urban sprawl have changed Scott County to where agriculture no longer is the dominant force. But farmers there still have clout, and the farm community is united and optimistic about agriculture’s future. Just ask Bill or Jimmy Bevins. They can tell you about the tremendous growth of the 68-year-old Bevins Motors farm equipment [&#8230;]]]></description>";

    NSString *urlString = [self getImageURLFromXML:input];

    if (urlString != nil)
    {
        // Use it
    }
    else
    {
        // No image link found
    }
}

- (NSString *)getImageURLFromXML:(NSString *)xml
{
    NSRange r1 = [xml rangeOfString:@"src=\""];
    NSString *extension;
    NSRange r2;

    if ([xml rangeOfString:@".jpg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        extension = @".jpg";
        r2 = [xml rangeOfString:@".jpg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }
    else if ([xml rangeOfString:@".png" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        extension = @".png";
        r2 = [xml rangeOfString:@".png" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }
    else if ([xml rangeOfString:@".gif" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        extension = @".gif";
        r2 = [xml rangeOfString:@".gif" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }
    else
    {
        // Hmm some other weird image extension, or no extension found

        return nil;
    }

    NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
    NSString *urlString = [xml substringWithRange:rSub];
    NSString *newUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",urlString,extension];

    NSLog(@"String is: %@",newUrlString);

    // Output: String is: http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/bevins-002-150x150.jpg

    return newUrlString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out, that [`<![CDATA[...]]>` is a well-formed construct within XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA). It allows to add data, that is not further interpreted as XML. Or comments, binary data…

NSXMLParser knows how to handle it via the delegate method `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock`

With this we can get the whole block in once, pass it to another parser and retrieve the information.

Here I let the same delegate parse it like the root document. In real world code this should be re-considered.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    self.cdatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock];
    self.cdatParser.delegate = self;
    [_cdatParser parse];
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if (parser == _cdatParser) {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]){
            NSLog(@"%@", attributeDict[@"src"]);
        }
    } else { // paser must be rootParser
        NSLog(@"%@", elementName);
    }
}
```

This will return

```
http://kyfbnewsroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/bevins-002-150x150.jpg
```

---

> *How would I then get just the description text?*

you can do following to get proper xml and parse it

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *cdataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    cdataString = [cdataString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cdataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<description>%@</description>", cdataString];
    self.cdatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[cdataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    self.cdatParser.delegate = self;
    [_cdatParser parse];
}
```

the description text will than be send to `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string`

---

my complete code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *rootParser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *cdatParser;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feed" ofType:@"xml"];

    NSError *e;
    NSString *contentOfFeed = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
    if (contentOfFeed) {
        self.rootParser= [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[contentOfFeed dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        self.rootParser.delegate = self;
        [self.rootParser parse];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", e.localizedDescription);
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if (parser == _cdatParser) {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]){
            NSLog(@"%@", attributeDict[@"src"]);
        }

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]){
            NSLog(@"start description");
        }
    } else { // paser must be rootParser
        NSLog(@"%@", elementName);
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


        NSLog(@"%@: end %@", (_cdatParser)?@"cdata":@"root" ,elementName);

}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (parser == _cdatParser) {
        NSLog(@"cdata: %@", string);

    } else { // paser must be rootParser
        NSLog(@"root: %@", string);
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *cdataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    cdataString = [cdataString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cdataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<description>%@</description>", cdataString];
    self.cdatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[cdataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    self.cdatParser.delegate = self;
    [_cdatParser parse];
}


@end
```

Comment: How would I then get just the description text?